# Websocket message from Django backend to javascript frontend

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

So I have correctly setup the Django consumer and routing for my websocket communication with DJango channel. The `consumers.py` and `routing.py` are in the same app where I want to use the `ws = create_connection("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/notifications")`

My issue is that, if I set a message from the backend with

```
    ws = create_connection("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/notifications")
    ws.send(json.dumps({"message": "Ricevuto"}))
    ws.close()
```

The frontend which is correctly connected to the same websocket with

```
  var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/notifications") // Creating a new Web Socket Connection

  // Socket On receive message Functionality
  socket.onmessage = function(e){
    console.log('message', e)
    console.log(e.data) // Access the notification data
  }

  // Socket Connet Functionality
  socket.onopen = function(e){
    console.log('open', e)
  }
```

seems to no receive the message even if the consumer on DJango correctly receive it

### consumer.py

```
import json

from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer


class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"message": "Benvenuto"}))

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    def receive(self, text_data):
        print(text_data)
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json["message"]

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"message": message}))
```

### routing.py

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"notifications", consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

### asgi.py

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns))
        ),
    }
)
```